# Popup menu pops under flash in Chrome,Opera and Safari

Tags: css, flash

I've created a popup navigation menu at: http://lixmebel.com -> under Галерия -> Проекти. In firefox and internet explorer everything works fine - the menu pops over the flash. But in Chrome, Safari and Opera the menu is behind the flash. Any ideas on how to fix this ?

Comment: Did you set the wmode to transparent?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `<embed>` tag, add this line: `wmode="transparent"`

```
<embed 
src="main.swf?xml_path=slides.xml" 
quality="high" 
width="560" 
height="480" 
name="tech" 
align="middle" 
allowscriptaccess="sameDomain" 
type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" 
wmode="transparent">
```

Tested in Chrome, works perfectly :)